# See ski trails in google earth

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

Is there a way to see the ski trails found on google maps for some mountains in google earth?

I've searched for a while now and can't find a solution, but doesn't make sense to me that the data would be available in one but not the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single place to go for ski trails, but there are a number of web sites with ski trails available in KML to view in Google Earth or Google Maps.

Really depends on what region you're looking for trail maps on.

[Skimap.org](http://skimap.org) claims to have the most ski resort trail maps on the internet. It is a good place to look for printed ski maps (scanned images) but some as layers for Google Earth in KML or integrated with Google Maps.

Here's specific one for the Whitefish Mountain in Montana
http://skiwhitefish.com/trailmaps.php

General list of ski areas in North America (sites not trails)
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=deb57fefa8d84b679bd02befd4ab3d5e

Check out this article [Skiing with OpenStreetMap](http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2011/03/skiing_with_openstreetmap.html) which has some related resources that might help.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I was talking specifically about the ski trails that have been added to google maps. Like here for sunday river in Maine: http://goo.gl/maps/yHtSx If google has the data to put them on gmaps, they should be available on google earth too right? Or are the products really that separated?

Comment: Looks like skimap.org can get me most of the way there by downloading and opening kmls. But still seems funny to me that these aren't built into google earth.

Comment: Not surprising since most of new development at Google of late is the new Google Maps and Google Earth to a lesser degree.